# Shabal256 code explanation

Tags: block, hash, algorithms

Can anyone please explain the code below with comments?

What are `pbegin` & `pend` ?

What is ( I believe it is data, where it comes from ?): `(pbegin == pend ? pblank : static_cast<const void*>(&pbegin[0]))`

What is (I believe it is the size of data 80?) : `(pend - pbegin) * sizeof(pbegin[0])`

What is : `pblank[1]`

```
template<typename T1>
inline uint256 HashShabal(const T1 pbegin, const T1 pend)
{    
    sph_shabal256_context ctx_shabal;
    static unsigned char pblank[1];
    uint256 hash[1];
    sph_shabal256_init(&ctx_shabal);
    // ZSHABAL;
    sph_shabal256 (&ctx_shabal, (pbegin == pend ? pblank : static_cast<const void*>(&pbegin[0])), (pend - pbegin) * sizeof(pbegin[0]));
    sph_shabal256_close(&ctx_shabal, static_cast<void*>(&hash[0]));

    return hash[0];
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where'd you find this?

Comment: @NickODell this can be found in most alt-coins that uses sphlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are pbegin & pend ?

Pointers to the beginning of the data and one byte past the end of the data, respectively. The function it's wrapping takes a pointer to the beginning plus the the size, so it needs to do some math with the pointers.

> What is (I believe it is data, where it comes from ?)

Presumably, if you found this code in a Bitcoin derivative, the data is a block header. This function might also be used to build a merkle tree. (Shabal256 appears to be fast enough for that.)

> What is : `pblank[1]`

A zero-length string. Presumably, sometimes this function gets called as `HashShabal(NULL, NULL)`, so this is for avoiding a null pointer exception.

> Can anyone please explain the code below with comments?

The purpose of this function appears to be to wrap the Shabal256 functions from [Projet RNRT SAPHIR](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/) to make them easier to use.